# Need title of 1980 - 1990 techno thriller about remote sensing technology

Tags: story-identification, technology, space, warfare

I read a military techno thriller in the 1980s - 1990s that I would like to identify by title and author. At the time I was heavily into this genre.  The book was about an advanced US technology that was developed that allowed its handlers to locate specific strategic metals with a remote probe/sensor. The technology is far superior to radar, sonar or any other current platform for remote sensing. Eventually this technology is sent into orbit on a satellite and it gives the US a strategic advantage.  As the technology is further developed it allows the handlers to dismantle/destroy objects made with strategic metals.  The story progresses and the new technology is used to halt an attack on the US.  Thank you for your help.

Although some elements are similar it is not "Silver Tower".

Comment: There's a 65% overlap there with [Silver Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Tower_(novel))...

Comment: Sounds like "The Trigger" by Micheal Kube McDonnell and Arthur C. Clarke.  In this book a small group of scientists discover a way to locate and ignite gunpowder at a distance.  As the technology is further developed it becomes more refined and more powerful with far reaching social implications.  The technology is "very close to magical" so I would not call this a techno=thriller.  There is the possibility that the authors have a very  poor understanding of what would happen if guns were eliminated.

Comment: The aliens in "War of the Worlds" by H.G. Wells (later a radio drama directed by Orson Welles and a recent movie starring Tom Cruise) had a device that detonated gunpowder at a distance.  <Arkady>